# Difference between sudo -u and su -c

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, su

The following is being executed from an account with sudo privileges:

I have a user `tomcat` created with the following command

```
sudo useradd -g tomcat -d /usr/local/tomcat -m -s /bin/false tomcat
```

I also have a user `test` created with the following command

```
sudo adduser test
```

I have a folder `temp` and perms `777` are set on this folder

```
chmod 777 temp
```

Following are my observations:

```
## This works and I can see temp/a.txt being created
sudo -u tomcat touch temp/a.txt 

## Does not work. 
sudo su -c "touch temp/b.txt" tomcat

## works
sudo -u test touch temp/c.txt

## works
sudo su -c "touch temp/d.txt" test
```

So my question is what exactly is wrong with tomcat user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tomcat's shell is /bin/false, you can run with su - as

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash -c "touch temp/b.txt" tomcat
```